# Jupyter in VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4jkri.png)

At first, jupyter notebook works fine. BUT, whenever I try to use the other ipynb file, jupyter notebook does not work and send this message. How should I deal with this?

Comment: did you check that you are in conda environment in your vs code?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, create a virtualenv. Open the terminal using Ctrl+Shift+`.

In the console, type `python3 -m venv venv`.

This will create a folder named `venv` in your working directory.

Now, in the bottom left corner, you will find the selected python interpreter. Click that and change it to `venv`.

(If windows raises permission error, In your vsCode settings, add the following lines.)

`"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": ["-ExecutionPolicy", "Bypass"]`

Now delete all previous terminals and open a new terminal.

Install the required packages using `pip` and carry on.

Comment: I already created a new virtualenv many times. sometimes It works fine.  After using several minutes, it doesn't work.
Can you explain following senteces in detail?
(If windows raises permission error, In your vsCode settings, add the following lines.)

"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": ["-ExecutionPolicy", "Bypass"]

Thank you!

Comment: Sometimes, Windows does not allow any script like "activate.ps1" to run. If that error raises, You can add those lines in your ```settings.json```. It will bypass the Script execution policy.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked which python interpreter you are using in the Jupyter Notebook?

[image]

With the different names of the `.ipynb` file, it will take the different kernels, and it is stored in the database.